# Сброс select не срабатывает

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
$("#metal-type").on("change", function () {
  $("li.filt").hide();
  $("option.filt").hide();
  $("#metal-try").val("");
  $("." + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="metal-type" id="metal-type" class="js-select fliter">
  <option value="1">- Выберите тип металла -</option>
  <option value="Платина">Платина</option>
  <option value="Золото">Золото</option>
  <option value="Серебро">Серебро</option>
</select>

<select name="metal-try" id="metal-try" class="js-select fliter delete">
  <option value="1">- Выберите пробу -</option>
  <option value="2">925</option>
</select>
```

При переключениями между #metal-type, select #metal-try должен сбрасываться, но почему-то этого не делает? В чём может быть причина? В cкрипте отвечает за это: `$("#metal-try").val("");`

Comment: вроде-бы все работает, а есть какие-то ошибки?

Comment: @Roman нету ошибок :(

Comment: при переключении `metal-type` - `metal-try` сбрасывается, какой работы кода вы ожидаете?

Comment: @Roman 

Действительно вижу, что здесь работает, но увы у меня нету, возможно есть ещё варианты как это другим способом сделать?

Comment: А вы случайно не подключили скрипт до HTML? И когда загружается скрипт, разметка еще не загружена, `alert( $("#metal-type").length ); // 0 ?`

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что правильно будет так:

```js
$("#metal-type").on("change", function() {
  $("#metal-try").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
  $("#metal-try option:gt(0)").hide();
  $("#metal-try option." + $(this).val()).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="metal-type" id="metal-type" class="js-select fliter">
  <option value="" disabled selected>- Выберите тип металла -</option>
  <option value="pt">Платина</option>
  <option value="au">Золото</option>
  <option value="ag">Серебро</option>
</select>

<select name="metal-try" id="metal-try" class="js-select fliter delete">
  <option value="" disabled selected>- Выберите пробу -</option>
  <option class="pt" value="585">585</option>
  <option class="pt" value="850">850</option>
  <option class="pt" value="900">900</option>
  <option class="pt" value="950">950</option>

  <option class="au" value="375">375</option>
  <option class="au" value="500">500</option>
  <option class="au" value="585">585</option>
  <option class="au" value="750">750</option>
  <option class="au" value="875">875</option>
  <option class="au" value="916">916</option>
  <option class="au" value="958">958</option>
  <option class="au" value="999">999</option>

  <option class="ag" value="800">800</option>
  <option class="ag" value="830">830</option>
  <option class="ag" value="875">875</option>
  <option class="ag" value="925">925</option>
  <option class="ag" value="960">960</option>
  <option class="ag" value="999">999</option>
</select>
```